# Bizarre SQL Server Permissions Question

Tags: sql-server, permissions

We have a system that uses a SQL server 2005 database with a number of views these are automatically run daily and the result sets emailed to the client.

I dont really know much about the system as a colleague of mine looks after it all but apparently its been working fine. We recently changed the admin password on the server SQL is installed on. Since then apparently a number of the views have stopped working. My colleague has said hes fixed the problem by dropping the views and recreating them.

As far as Im concerened the server admin password should have nothing to do with the views, as the application that runs them is using SQL authentication with its own login.

Any ideas what could have caused this? All the views seem to be in the DBO schema and not tied to any particular user account.  I'm not convinced its anything to do with the server admin login password changing but just wanted to hear your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say the views stopped working, can you please expand on this? Did they return an error message, and if so what was the error?

Comment: Unfortunatly I dont know, as I say a colleague is looking after this. Just wondered if there was anything obvious. But its looking like there is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The views should continue to work.  Perhaps you have the sa password hardcoded somewhere in your process.